Общая сумма списков
Согласно сайту www.bodycounters.com в четырех частях фильма “Пираты Карибского моря” было довольно много погибших.
Напишите скрипт, который считает общее число погибших живых существ во всех сериях.Пиратов-зомби в последней части тоже считайте живыми.
bodycount = {
    'Проклятие Черной жемчужины': {
        'человек': 17
    },

    'Сундук мертвеца': {
        'человек': 56,
        'раков-отшельников': 1
    },

    'На краю света': {
        'человек': 88
    },

    'На странных берегах': {
        'человек': 56,
        'русалок': 2,
        'ядовитых жаб': 3,
        'пиратов зомби': 2
    }
}


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Самый примитивный способ решить задачу.
Инициализируем переменную counter, в неё мы будем помещать искомые числа.
Далее перебираем значения словаря bodycount, используя .values(), и ещё раз повторяем операцию. Затем суммируем и выводим
counter = 0
for i in bodycount.values():
    for count in i.values():
        counter += count
print(counter)


не следует давать ответы на вопросы, в которых автор даже не пытался решать задачу самостоятельно.
